# How to remove the little space between h1 & inner a

Tags: css

With markup like

http://jsfiddle.net/rUsbJ/

```
<h1><a href="#">Header with link</a></h1>
<h1>Header without link</h1>
```

[image]

As you can see theres some space between the `<a>` and the parent `<h1>`. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the anchor to `display:inline-block` or just `display:block`

(anchors are by default inline-level)

---

Although in my browser (Chrome 9), both H1 elements have the same height: http://jsfiddle.net/rUsbJ/1/